# react-native run-android is returning: failed to execute aapt. for react-naitve-push-notification

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-push-notification

**When I run react-native run android I get the error:**

Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:processReleaseResources'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
This is preventing a succefful build and installation of the app. However, gradlew clean is successful.

**Expected result:**

the build should finish and the apk installed on the app

**Actual results:**

gradlew clean produces a successful build. The build crashes when react-native run-android is ran.  The following error is produced:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:processReleaseResources'.
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

**I have tried the following solutions:**

1. including android.enableAapt2=false into my gradle.
2. including android.enableAapt2=true into my gradle.properties
3. running gradlew clean
4. changing my build tools and sdk versions
5. including the following into my build.gradle file

   subprojects { 
             afterEvaluate { 
                 project -> if (project.hasProperty("android")) { 
                     android { 
                         compileSdkVersion 26 
                        buildToolsVersion '26.0.3' 
                   } 
                } 
            }   }
6. reducing the length of my project path
7. re-linking the project

**Current Code**

**inside app/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
             maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
           maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }

    }
}
```

**inside android/build.gradle**

```
 compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"

        aaptOptions {  
    cruncherEnabled = false  
} 

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.raingemain.beta"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 10
        versionName "10.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

**logs when I run it with --stacktrace**

org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:processReleaseResources'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:185)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:245)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:232)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:873)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:178)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 'C:\Users\Carrie\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe' with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Carrie\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar -M C:\Users\Carrie\Documents\range-app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Carrie\Documents\range-app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release -m -J C:\Users\Carrie\Documents\range-app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\build\generated\source\r\release --custom-package com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification --non-constant-id -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Carrie\Documents\range-app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\build\intermediates\bundles\release --no-version-vectors}
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:871)
        ... 69 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 'C:\Users\Carrie\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe' with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\Carrie\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar -M C:\Users\Carrie\Documents\range-app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\release\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Carrie\Documents\range-app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\release -m -J C:\Users\Carrie\Documents\range-app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\build\generated\source\r\release --custom-package com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification --non-constant-id -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\Carrie\Documents\range-app\node_modules\react-native-push-notification\android\build\intermediates\bundles\release --no-version-vectors}
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:75)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:60)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Carrie\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:47)
        ... 9 more

BUILD FAILED

Comment: Did you run react-native link react-native-push-notification?

Comment: @joseporto yes i did and it did not work. In addition I went through the manual linking instructions to check if anything was missed.